# multiple insert of a result of a script

Tags: php, sql, loops, insert

I am trying to import the content of some links into a database using the following script

```
$url = "http://example.com";
$html = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
$extract = str_replace("'", "\'", $html);

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO links (url, text) values ('".$url."', '".$extract."')";
```

I have a list of 500+ links that I want to run the script above against, but I want to do it all together and not link by link.

Is there a way to do it with loop or I have to do it with a different logic?

Comment: [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) you can find how INSERT works, to be more specific it allows to insert multiple rows in one single query using the following sintax: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`, assuming you are using MySQL, but I guess it's almost the same for the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can it with loop. Define an array will all the links/urls. Loop it to get the text and run insert query.

```
// define an array
$links = array('http://example.com', 
'http://example1.com', 
'http://example2.com',
.........
'http://example500.com',
);

// loop the array
foreach($links as $link){
    $url = $link;
    $html = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
    $extract = str_replace("'", "\'", $html);
    // insert query
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO links (url, text) values ('".$url."', '".$extract."')";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the links into a file (one link per line), then use the `file()` function to put the links into an array so you can loop over, like this:

```
$urls = file('links.txt');
foreach($urls as $url) {
    $html = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
    $extract = str_replace("'", "\'", $html);
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO links (url, text) values ('".$url."', '".$extract."')"; 
}
```

Also, I don't know what database engine are you using, but I recommend you to read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as concatenating values within the SQL instruction leads to security issues.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. Its mysql that I am using